# Technical background to the C++ fmt::print vs. fmt::format_to naming?

Tags: c++, c++20, api-design, fmt

Why is it `fmt::format_to(OutputIt, ...)` and not `fmt::print(OutputIt, ...)`??

---

I'm currently familiarizing myself with [`{fmt}`](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html), a / the modern C++ formatting library.

While browsing the API, I found the naming a bit disjoint, but given my little-to-no experience with the library (and my interest in API design), I would like to get behind these naming choices: ([fmt core API reference](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#core-api))

- There's `fmt::format(...) -> std::string` which makes sense, it returns a formatted string.
- Then we have `void fmt::print([stream, ] ...)` which also makes sense naming wise (certainly given the `printf` legacy).
- But *then* we have `fmt::format_to(OutputIt, ...) -> OutputIt` which resembles, apart from the return type, what `print` does with streams.

Now obviously, one can bike shed names all day, but here the question is *not* on why we have `format` vs. `print` (which is quite explainable to me), but why a function that clearly(?) behaves like the write-to-stream-kind has been bundled with the `format_...` naming style.

So, as the question title already asks, is there a **technical difference** in how `fmt::print(stream, ...)` behaves when formatting to a streams vs. how `fmt::format_to(OutputIt, ...)` behaves when formatting to an output iterator?

Or was/is this purely a style choice? Also, given that the [GitHube repo](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) explicitly lists the [fmt](/questions/tagged/fmt) tag here, I was hoping that we could get a authoritative answer on this from the original API authors.

Comment: Names are hard. :) Interested to see where this goes.

Comment: Hard? Naming is a <expletive deleted>ing battlefield. Complete with mines, barbed wire, artillery, and trenches.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - Personally I think we need a naming-is-hard tag, but I feel I'm in the minority on this one :-D

Comment: Do not know if that is relevant to your question, but the `fmt` library made it to C++ standard and is now [part of C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format). However that process dropped `print` entirely. And it looks like it in fact never was part of the proposal, even the [first draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0645r0.html).

Comment: Note that `print` only takes in C `FILE` stream, whereas `format_to` takes in any output iterators, includes containers' and C++ streams'.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep `print` takes a `std::ostream&` if you `#include <fmt/ostream.h>`. AFAIK, `format_to` can't directly write to a `std::ostream&`.

Comment: @user4581301 - I always feel more like Naming is rather like a swampy jungle. You wander in, thinking yeah, maybe one way is a little easier than the other, but maybe we could take that shortcut (on which your team obv. disagrees) and in the end you spent hours upon hours and feel lucky to have come out at all. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it would be possible to name `format_to` `print`, the former is closer conceptually to `format` than to `print`. `format_to` is a generalization of `format` that writes output via an output iterator instead of `std::string`. Therefore the naming reflects that.

`print` without a stream argument on the other hand writes to `stdout` and `print` with an argument generalizes that to an arbitrary stream. Writing to a stream is fundamentally different from writing to an output iterator because it involves additional buffering, synchronization, etc. Other languages normally use "print" for this sort of functionality so this convention is followed in {fmt}.

This becomes blurry because you can have an output iterator that writes to a stream but even there the current naming reflects what high-level APIs are being used.

In other words `format_to` is basically a fancy STL algorithm (there is even `format_to_n` similarly to `copy`/`copy_n`) while `print` is a formatted output function.